# How is the result returned in SharpDX.DirectInput.Device.Acquire()?

Tags: sharpdx, directinput

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinputdevice8.idirectinputdevice8.acquire%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `IDirectInputDevice8::Acquire` says:

> Return Value
>
> If the method succeeds, the return value is `DI_OK`, or
>   `S_FALSE` if the device was already acquired. If the method fails, the
>   return value can be one of the following error values:
>   `DIERR_INVALIDPARAM`, `DIERR_NOTINITIALIZED`, `DIERR_OTHERAPPHASPRIO`.

However, SharpDX's `Device.Acquire()` is a `void`. The [documentation](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-directinput-device-acquire) for this method  is not really helpful.

How can I know if a call to `Device.Aquire()` has succeeded or not?

Alternatively, where is the source for `Acquire()` located? I've tried looking at the [contents](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.DirectInput/Device.cs) of `Device.cs`, but not only it is not located in there, but `Device` is marked as `partial`, which means the source for `Acquire()` is probably in a different file, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to use the Acquire method is to assume it has worked correctly - if it fails to acquire the device, a SharpDXException will be thrown from the Acquire method. In this way, there is no need for a return value.

A disassembly of the Acquire method shows the code as:

```
public unsafe void Acquire()
{
  // ISSUE: cast to a function pointer type
  // ISSUE: function pointer call
  (Result) (__calli((__FnPtr<int (void*)>) *(IntPtr*) (*(IntPtr*) this._nativePointer + IntPtr(7) * sizeof (void*)))(this._nativePointer)).CheckError();
}
```

The CheckError call is a method on the Result struct, which looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks the error.
/// </summary>
public void CheckError()
{
    if (_code < 0)
    {
        throw new SharpDXException(this);
    }
}
```

(Source from https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/b1596ddd38a5de77704412910a4fb265a4ab8525/Source/SharpDX/Result.cs)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could invoke `GetLastError()`. but depending on how your program is structured it might contain a stale value (for example, if an earlier call failed and `Acquire()` succeeded but did not clear the error code) and it might not be accurate depending on how that SharpDX function is written.

You could work around the "stale" issue by invoking `SetLastError()` to prime (clear) the error code before invoking SharpDX.